# Bash AWK variable substitution

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to read from another variable which will have some text in it:

```
index:index.html:index2.html:index3.html
```

I want the variable "a" to be equal to each "index.html" at a time so that I can run another command on the variable a, but when the awk command increments, the variable a is just blank. Below is my code

```
index="index:index.html:index2.html:index3.html"
counter=4
a=$(echo $index | awk -F: '{for(i=3;i<$counter;i++){printf $i}}')
```

Comment: If all you want to do is separate this colon-delimited fields in a string for handling in a shell script, why bother piping your stuff through `awk`? Just `man bash` and read about `IFS`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Pass the variable `counter` to awk, use `print` instead of `printf`, make `a` variable an array

```
index="index:index.html:index2.html:index3.html"
counter=4
a=( $(echo "$index" | awk -F: -v counter=$counter '{for(i=1;i<counter;i++){print $i}}') )
echo "${a[*]}"
```

Result

`index index.html index2.html`

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors with your `awk` program, but if you're using `awk` just to split the file names, then it would be much simpler if you don't use `awk`. Something like these two solutions:

**One file at a time:**

```
OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=:

index="index:index.html:index2.html:index3.html"
for a in $index
do
    # here whatever you want to do with $a
    echo "Value of a is '$a'"
done

IFS="$OLD_IFS"
```

**Using an array**:

```
OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=:

index="index:index.html:index2.html:index3.html"
array=( $index )
for a in "${array[@]}"
do
    # here whatever you want to do with $a
    echo "Value of a is '$a'"
done

IFS="$OLD_IFS"
```

Both solutions have the same output:

```
Value of a is 'index'
Value of a is 'index.html'
Value of a is 'index2.html'
Value of a is 'index3.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

By asking how to achieve this *with a particular tool* (awk) you may be asking an [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

I would submit that you can avoid awk altogether, and just handle everything in bash.

```sh
$ index="index:index.html:index2.html:index3.html"
$ IFS=:
$ declare a=( $index )
$ printf '%d\n' "${#a[@]}"     # here's your field count...
4
$ declare -p a
declare -a a=([0]="index" [1]="index.html" [2]="index2.html" [3]="index3.html")
$ printf '> %s\n' "${a[@]}"
> index
> index.html
> index2.html
> index3.html
```

Or if, as you say, you want to run another command on each element of this array, you can use a for loop on the array elements:

```
$ for file in "${a[@]}"; do printf '>> %s\n' "$file"; done
>> index
>> index.html
>> index2.html
>> index3.html
```